# Filter JSON value to Category ,show on RecycleView in android retrofit

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, retrofit

I have an JSON sample about  like this:

```
[
  {
"Id": 549,
"Name": "ESPRESSO 1",
"Type": "COFFEE",

  },
  {
"Id": 550,
"TenHangHoa": "ESPRESSO 2",
"Type": "COFFEE",
  },
  {
"Id": 567,
"Name": "YOGUST 1",
"Type": "YOGUST SHAKE",
  },
  {
"Id": 568,
"Name": "YOGUST  2",
"Type": "YOGUST SHAKE", 
  },
]
```

My POJO:

```
public class Drink{
  private String Id;
  private String Name;
  private String Type;

  get...set
}
```

IMAGE

[image]

1. How to parse json array response by Type
2. How to save it as a list
3. Pass the list to a recyclerview adapter and then attach the adapter to recyclerview.

Comment: your question is too broad since it include a lot of sub questions like `1. How to parse json array response 2. How to save it as a list 3. Pass the list to a recyclerview adapter and then attach the adapter to recyclerview`. Try breaking down your question into a **`specific topic`**

Comment: tks @NavneetKrishna i will edit it right now.I'm sorry,this is the first time i use stackoverflow